# Hibernate. Multiple Parameters on session.get()

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there a way run multiple parameters through session.get() in Hibernate?

```
public User method(String param1, String param2) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (User) session.get(User.class, param1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Session#get](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) is used to fetch an entity by the associated entity identifier.

A table can have one primary key, even when the primary key is built out of several columns. The table row is mapped to an entity, hence the entity can have only one identifier (even if the identifier may be built out of several properties).

That's why this method only takes one parameter. If you want to filter entities by more parameters, you then need to run a [query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29) instead.